# Updating complex objects

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I'm mainly looking at usage of Dapper, but in general, any comments relating SQL -> C# object mapping best practices would be appreciated.

I've got two super simple objects I'm working with:

```
public class Subcategory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Subcategories = new List<Subcategory>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

`Id` for both of them is set by the db on insert via T-SQL's `newsequentialid()`.

I'm writing repository classes for each of the objects that conform to the following interface (actually implemented via an abstract class):

```
public interface IMaintanceRepository<T> where T: class
{
    Guid Create(T toCreate);
    T Read(Guid id);
    T Update(T toUpdate);
    void Delete(Guid id);
}
```

Right now, I'm trying to write the `Update` method in the `Category` repository. I have the following written, but I'm not sure if it's the most performant Dapper code as written.

```
public override Category Update(Category toUpdate)
{
    var deleteRemovedSubcategories = @"
        DELETE FROM dbo.Subcategories 
        WHERE CategoryId = @Id 
            AND Id NOT IN @Ids";

    var addNewSubcategories = @"
        INSERT INTO dbo.Subcategories (CategoryId, Name)
        VALUES (@CategoryId, @Name)";

    var updateExistingSubcategories = @"
        CREATE TABLE #subcategories (
            Id uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
            CategoryId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
            Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
        );

        INSERT INTO #subcategories VALUES (@Id, @CategoryId, @Name);

        UPDATE s1
        SET s1.CategoryId = s2.CategoryId, s1.Name = s2.Name
        FROM dbo.Subcategories s1
        INNER JOIN #subcategories s2
        ON s1.Id = s2.Id;

        DROP TABLE #subcategories;";

    var updateCategory = @"
        UPDATE dbo.Categories
        SET Name = @Name
        OUTPUT INSERTED.*
        WHERE Id = @Id;

        SELECT * FROM dbo.Subcategories WHERE CategoryId = @Id";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Execute(deleteRemovedSubcategories, new { Id = toUpdate.Id, Ids = toUpdate.Subcategories.Select(s => s.Id) });
        connection.Execute(addNewSubcategories, toUpdate.Subcategories.Where(s => s.Id == Guid.Empty));
        connection.Execute(updateExistingSubcategories, toUpdate.Subcategories);
        using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(updateCategory, toUpdate))
        {
            var category = multi.ReadSingle<Category>();
            category.Subcategories = multi.Read<Subcategory>().ToList();
            return category;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any suggested improvements to doing something like this?

Comment: Also worth noting, the queries executed are extremely order dependent currently, which makes me feel a little uneasy. In particular the `deleteRemovedSubcategories` query would delete new `Subcategory`-ies added via `addNewSubcategories`. I'm not sure if my intuition about this is misplaced though.

Comment: Why are you inserting into a #temp to update regular table?

Comment: @Paparazzi, I want to bulk load to a temp table so I can offload the update to the DB. Changes number of times I need to transfer data across the DB connection from N (number of updates to make) to 1.

Comment: @Paparazzi, Dapper converts the `VALUES (/* params */)` into a bulk-load statement, [per their documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#execute-a-command-multiple-times). It's not just one row, confirmed via testing.

Comment: It's passing `toUpdate.Subcategories`, which is an `ICollection<Subcategory>` per the class in the question. Dapper supposedly bulk-loads anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which is what you'd want.

Comment: is this real production code?

Comment: Just in development at the moment, and it's a pet project to learn things atm, but does have some shipping potential.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Malachi, fair enough. Didn't know about that page, or the rules. The reason I didn't accept that answer was external to the improvements it suggested however though. It didn't actually address the issue at hand. I took it as a suggestion to further the ability to get more answers, so I made the modifications to help readability.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at what you had coded here

> ```
> var deleteRemovedSubcategories = @"
>     DELETE FROM dbo.Subcategories 
>     WHERE CategoryId = @Id 
>         AND Id NOT IN @Ids";
> ```

and it took me a minute to figure out exactly what the Where clause was filtering, what finally gave it away was the name of the C# variable `deleteRemovedSubcategories`. If it were possible I would change some of these column names and/or T-SQL variables so that it is more clear what you are saying here.

Comment: Useful feedback. Column IDs could definitely be prefixed with the object name. That's confused me a time or two. My question was more geared towards evaluating the usage of dapper though, not coding standards. I'll update the question to be more specific. +1 though!